# Angular Dialog - access variable from child component

Tags: dialog, parent-child, angular-reactive-forms

I have a component which has a function to open a dialog of another component:

```
open() {
        this.dialogRef = this.dialog.open(ChildComponent);

        this.dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
            this.dialogRef = null;
        });
    }
```

From this parent component, I want to access a variable from the ChildComponent. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

You can access variable of chile dialog component with componentInstance field.
e.g.

> `this.dialogRef.componentInstance.variableName`